# Copying from remote server to local using SCP/ Name of service not know ssh error

Tags: server, ssh, scp

I am trying to copy a folder from a secured remote server to my local disk.
When I try to copy with the following:

```
[banikr@vcn1 rat_SCI_data]$ scp -r /MAL_Test_Case/ banikr2@banikr:/media/banikr2/DATA/MAL/fromfmri/
```

I get the following error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname banikr: Name or service not known
lost connection
```

To be exact  I want to copy `MAL_Test_Case` to my local path/drive.

Any help?

Comment: "*Could not resolve hostname `banikr`*" is a pretty decent error description. Did you investigate in this direction?

Comment: Yeah I did. In all the discussions `ssh` was used and I actually tried that without any luck. And not one I found so far that has `scp` involved too.

Comment: You say you want to copy a file **from** a remote server, yet you are giving a local source path `/`. I *suspect* that you have SSH'd in to the remote server and are trying to push the file back to your local machine, which likely isn't running an SSH server or isn't accessible from the public network. Instead, use scp from the *local* machine to pull the file.

Comment: I actually found a workaround. I used scp from my local terminal and copied from remote one. Then it only asks for pw. 
`banikr2@banikr:/media/banikr2/DATA/MAL$ scp -r banikr@vcn1.org:/home/primatefmri/SCI_data/MAL_Test_Case fromfmri/`
This actually worked.

Comment: @steeldriver good find, I guess you should post it as answer :-)